# can we use a custom teams template to request a new teams team(failed)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I just created a custom team template via admin center and then copied the teamplateid
and then tried to use graph api to request a new team site but failed.
My request body is

```
{
   "template@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('xxxxxxxxx-a6b0-4bd5-8a4e-dabf9bb4b702')",
   "displayName":"My Sample Team1",
   "description":"My Sample Team’s Description",
   "visibility": "Public",
   "members":[
      {
         "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
         "roles":[
            "owner"
         ],
         "userId":"xxxxxxxx-f0a3-4105-b41e-1ba89f05911c"
      }
   ]
}
```

encountered this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest. Request Url: https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/emea/templates/api/team, Request Method: POST, Response Status Code: BadRequest, Response Headers: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000\r\nx-operationid: c9ea1a0ae318f144b5b2fa88663f7d2a\r\nx-telemetryid: 00-c9ea1a0ae318f144b5b2fa88663f7d2a-ff60c4978218794d-00\r\nX-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 9406390A3B7E4E3C8408DC1F620A6AE5 Ref B: DB3EDGE1021 Ref C: 2020-11-12T09:09:34Z\r\nDate: Thu, 12 Nov 2020 09:09:33 GMT\r\n, ErrorMessage : {\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"A template with id 'ffc586b1-a6b0-4bd5-8a4e-dabf9bb4b702' and locale 'en-US' could not be found.\"}],\"operationId\":\"c9ea1a0ae318f144b5b2fa88663f7d2a\"}",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-11-12T09:09:34",
      "request-id": "7d148a1c-6de7-42c6-9580-760bcc56eecf",
      "client-request-id": "7d148a1c-6de7-42c6-9580-760bcc56eecf"
    }
  }
}
```

By using the default template and copied the basetemplateid,I could successfully submit the request.
But can not use the custom template id!

Comment: How long did you wait after creating custom team template? In this documentation, it states clearly that custom templates take 24 hours to see it in gallery. You can get more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/create-a-team-template)

Comment: well, I haven't tried so long. I will follow this note and do it again. Thanks!

Comment: @Manish-MSFT I tried it in 3-days but still got the same error.

Comment: Hmm, could you try one more time. Just in case to be on same lines so that I can take this forward to respective development team.

Comment: It's weird we lost that custom template last time! I added a new one and now it works!

Comment: I remember a related thread in the same lines. Adding it for reference - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10774